# How do I find set expressions that corresponds do regions on a Venn diagram?

Tags: statistics

Consider the Venn diagram below, where sets A and B are subsets of the universal set represented by the box
 [image: venn diagram]

a) Find a set expression that corresponds to the black region in the diagram.

b) Find an equivalent set expression for the black region that includes all four set operations: union, intersection, complement, and difference.

[Bonus]

c) Do you think there is a maximum (i.e. finite) number of ways to represent this region using set operations? Explain your reasoning.
If you want to avoid using an equation editor, or special symbols, you may use the following notation using your standard keyboard to display set operations:
A' = Complement of set A
A U B = Union of sets A and B
A INT B = Intersection of sets A and B
A - B = Difference of set B from set A

Answer (score 0):

The region can be described  as being $(A \cup B)-(A\cap B)$

A different way is $(A \cap B') \cup (A' \cap B)$

I try to think of it like an area problem. For example, the first way is basically take the middle overlap from the rest of the shaded  bits.